# noexcept operator with lambdas. MSVC bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, noexcept

It appears that MSVC treats all lambdas as noexcept. This code compiles in msvc 19.28 (checked in Compiler Explorer), but expectedly fails the static assertion in gcc:

```
void foo() {
  auto lambda_may_throw = [] {};

  static_assert(noexcept(lambda_may_throw()));
}
```

What is interesting is that I googled a bit but was unable to find any info on this issue. Is this really an msvc bug or just me failing to understand something?

Comment: What is also interesting is that this still fails to compile in MSVC:  void(*ptr)() noexcept = lambda_may_throw; but changing the lambda to   auto lambda_may_throw = [] () noexcept {}; fixes it! So MSVC is still aware of noexcept modifier on lambda, but treats is weirdly

Comment: I am vaguely surprised we don't have a default "noexcept is the conjunction of the noexcept of the statements within" if not provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is only observed with `/permissive`.
When compiling with `/permissive-`, the assert triggers.

So perhaps it is a compatibility extension to support older Visual Studio code.

(You also may observe that it fails with `/std:c++latest` and compiles with `/std:c++17` without specifying `/permissive-`. This is not the difference in standards, rather `/std:c++latest` also implies `/permissive-` by default)

Comment: Thank you! /permissive- solves my issue, but I'm kind of surprised that a behavior that  basically contradicts the standard (c++ 17) is the default even when /std:c++17 switch is specified.